# Bash - While loop doesn't stop

Tags: bash, while-loop

I've written a script where I have a while loop. I've tried two similar looking conditions but for some weird reason one of the condition works but the other doesn't.

Works, the loop stops as expected.

```
function finder {
    # it prints an integer
}

for ((current = 1; current <= $total_lines; current++)); do
    foo=$(( current - 1 ))
    while [ "$(finder $foo)" = "0" ]; do
        (( foo-- ))
    done
done
```

Doesn't work, the while loop never stops.

```
function finder {
    # it prints an integer
}

for ((current = 1; current <= $total_lines; current++)); do
    foo=$(( current - 1 ))
    while [[ $(finder $foo) -eq 0 ]]; do
        (( foo-- ))
    done
done
```

My actual question is what are the differences between these conditions? I want the 2nd condition to work somehow.

```
while [ "$(finder $foo)" = "0" ];
# versus
while [[ $(finder $foo) -eq 0 ]];
```

Comment: `foo=((` is invalid. Don't you get a syntax error? `it returns an integer` does the function __return__ an integer or prints an integer? Your code checks If it prints an integer.

Comment: @KamilCuk Typing mistakes sorry. Forgot to add ```$```.

Comment: @KamilCuk it prints an integer

Comment: Are you asking XY question?

Comment: @KamilCuk yeah, it's an XY question.

Comment: Are you *sure* that `finder` is printing an integer? What exactly is it printing when the loop should stop but doesn't? Putting `set -x` before the problem section may clarify what's going on here.

Comment: @Arghadip : From looking at your code, it's the other way round: the second one looks more reasonable than the first, although I had written it still differently: `while (( $(finder $foo) == 0 ))`. Of course, if `finder` returns garbage, than - depending on the kind of garbage - it may well be that the real problem is in your `finder` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My actual question is what's the difference between these conditions?
>
> ```
> while [ "$(finder $foo)" = "0" ];
> # versus
> while [[ $(finder $foo) -eq 0 ]];
> ```

To summarize:

| `[ "$(finder $foo)" = "0" ];` | `[[ $(finder $foo) -eq 0 ]]` |
| --- | --- |
| portable and POSIX compatible | bash specific |
| calls a `[` or `test` command | calls a bash (very) special builtin `[[` |
| compares the strings as they are | does arithmetic expansion before comparing |
| does string comparison | does arithmetic comparison |
| uses quoting `"` to disable word splitting and filename expansion | special semantics of `[[` disable word splitting and filename expansion |

Comment: So In sort, can I use ```[[ $(finder $foo) -eq 0 ]]``` for my current purpose? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Yes. No idea - present an [MCVE]. Please see [ask].